# If $(c_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers and if $\sum_n c_n\sin{nx}$ is uniformly convergent, then $\lim{(nc_n)}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(c_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers. If $\sum_n c_n\sin{nx}$ is uniformly convergent, then show that $\lim{(nc_n)}=0$.

This problem is from the book *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Bartle and Sherbert. I attempted it several times but never could get anywhere near the solution. Any help? Thanks and regards.

Comment: do you want an hint or only a full solution ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis : As I tried this problem for quite a long time, I think it would be good enough if you can mention only the key points and observations regarding it. I guess I can fill up the rest of it.

Comment: don't have a full proof yet, could you tell us what you tried, maybe than i know if my idea works or not

Comment: I think I have something maybe. If it is uniformly convergent then the series converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, I assume since it isn't stated otherwise, so if we choose $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we get that $$\sum_n c_n \sin(n \frac{\pi}{2})$$ converges and hence $c_n \sin(n\frac{\pi}{2}) \rightarrow 0$ and so the even $n$ is the constant sequence $0$ and the odd $n$ are gives the subsequence $(c_1,-c_3,c_5,...)$ and every subsequence of a convergence sequence has the limit of the sequence so $(c_1,-c_3,...) \rightarrow 0$ so the absolute value of the subsequence goes to zero

Comment: but the $c_n$ is a decreasing sequence so then if the odd terms go to $0$ then the even terms will be in between them to the $c_n$ must go to zero as well, sound good? Only thing is I am just using since the series is uniformly convergent then the series must converge, I don't seem to be using anything that seems particular to uniform convergence.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis : It's not very substantial. I primarily tried to use the the Cauchy criterion on the partial sum sequence $s_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k \sin{kc_k}$ and then use the property that $(c_n)$ is decreasing. But the inequalities are giving me a hell lot of trouble.

Comment: i am thinking about to use that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sin(kx)$ is not uniformly convergent

Comment: @Wishingwell: I thought about using $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ at one point, but abandoned the idea because then I had to deal with both positive and negative terms. Anyway, your argument that $c_n \to 0$ when the odd-indexed terms go to $0$ sounds really nice to me. At least it's a new way to think about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is $\epsilon > 0$ and $n_1,n_2,n_3,...$ going to infinity such that $n_k c_{n_k} > \epsilon $ for each $k$. We will show that the series cannot converge uniformly.

Since $\sin(x) > {1 \over 2} x$ whenever $0 < x < 1$, whenever $0 < x < {1 \over n_k}$ one has
$$\sum_{{n_k \over 2} \leq n \leq n_k} c_n \sin{nx} > {x \over 2} \sum_{{n_k \over 2} \leq n \leq n_k} n c_n$$
Since the $c_n$ are decreasing, this is at least
$$ {x \over 2} \sum_{{n_k \over 2} \leq n \leq n_k} n c_{n_k}$$
$$ \geq {x \over 2} \sum_{{n_k \over 2} \leq n \leq n_k} {n_k \over 2}c_{n_k}$$
$$ \geq {x \over 2}({n_k \over 2} - 1){n_k \over 2}c_{n_k}$$
We have ${n_k \over 2} - 1$ here in case $n_k$ is odd. So if $x = {1 \over 2n_k}$ for example, we therefore have
$$\sum_{{n_k \over 2} \leq n \leq n_k} c_n \sin{nx} > {1 \over 4n_k}({n_k \over 2} - 1){n_k \over 2}c_{n_k}$$
$$\geq {1 \over 16} n_k c_{n_k}$$
$$\geq {\epsilon \over 16}$$
Thus the terms of the series from ${\displaystyle {n_k \over 2}}$ to ${\displaystyle n_k}$ sum to at least ${\displaystyle{\epsilon \over 16}}$ at one point. Thus if we choose a sequence of such ${\displaystyle n_k}$'s, call them ${\displaystyle n_{k_l}}$, such that ${\displaystyle n_{k_l} > 2 n_{k_{l-1}}}$ we see the sum cannot converge uniformly; the next bracket of terms from ${\displaystyle n = {n_{k_l} \over 2}}$ to ${\displaystyle n = n_{k_l}}$ will always contribute at least ${\displaystyle{\epsilon \over 16}}$ at some $x$.

Comment: Even if $n_k$ is odd you can estimate the number of terms by $\frac{n_k}{2}$. No real harm in underestimating them, of course, but it seems that in the second to last freestanding inequality you need $\frac{n_k}{2}$, not $(\frac{n_k}{2}-1)$.

Comment: @Johan I think it's correct... say if $n_k = 3$ you bound below by $1 = {3 - 1 \over 2}$. And since these are lower bounds it never hurts to remove 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch:

1. $c_n \to c$. Prove that $c = 0$. For this, choose $p$ very high, $x = 1/p$. By uniform continuity,$$f(x) - \varepsilon < c_1\mbox{sin }x + .... + c_p\mbox{sin }px < f(x) + \varepsilon$$ Now all the terms are positive, so $$c_1\mbox{sin }x + .... + c_p\mbox{sin }px \geq c(\mbox{sin }x + .... + \mbox{sin }px)$$ making $f(x)$ blow up at $0$, unless $c$ itself is $0$.
2. Next rewrite your series as $$\sum \bigg[a_1\frac{\mbox{sin }x}{1} + .... + a_p\frac{\mbox{sin }px}{p} + ....\bigg]$$. WLOG (descending to a subsequence if need be) you can assume that $|a_p| > \delta$ for all $p$. Then, $$ a_1\frac{\mbox{sin }x}{1} + .... + a_p\frac{\mbox{sin }px}{p} \geq \delta\mbox{sin }x[1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{p}]$$, which still blows up at $0$ because of $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{sin y}{y} = 1$.